# Theorem 18.4 of Munkres’ Topology

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing, solution-verification, alternative-proof

> (Maps into product) let $f: A\to X\times Y$ be given by equation $f(a)=(f_1 (a), f_2 (a))$ then f is continuous if and only if the function $f_1 : A\to X$ and $f_2 :A\to Y$ are continuous.

**My attempt:** let $x\in A$. Let $U\in \mathcal{N}_{f_1 (x)}$ and $V\in \mathcal{N}_{f_2 (x)}$. Since $f$ is continuous at $x$, $\forall P\in \mathcal{N}_{f(x)}, \exists Q\in \mathcal{N}_x$ such that $f(Q)\subseteq P$. Clearly $U\times V\in \mathcal{B}\subseteq \mathcal{T}_{X\times Y}$ and $(f_1 (x), f_2 (x))\in U\times V$. So $U\times V \in \mathcal{N}_{f(x)}$. Take $Q\in \mathcal{N}_{x}$ so that $f(Q)\subseteq U\times V$. $f(Q)=\{ f(z)\in X\times Y| z\in Q\} \subseteq U\times V$. So $f(z)=(f_1 (z),f_2 (z))\in U\times V, \forall z\in Q$. Thus, $f_1 (Q)=\{ f_1(z)| z\in Q\} \subseteq U$ and $f_2 (Q)=\{ f_2(z)| z\in Q\} \subseteq V$. Hence $f_1$ and $f_2$ are continuous.

Conversely, let $x\in A$ and $V\in \mathcal{N}_{f(x)}$. Which means $(f_1 (x), f_2 (x))\in V$ and $V=\bigcup_{i\in I} (U_i \times V_i)$, where $(U_i \times V_i) \in \mathcal{B}, \forall i\in I$. So $(f_1 (x), f_2 (x)) \in (U_j \times V_j)$, for some $j\in I$. So $U_j \in \mathcal{N}_{f_1 (x)}$ and $V_j \in \mathcal{N}_{f_2 (x)}$. Since $x\in A$ and $f_1$ & $f_2$ are continuous, $\exists R,S \in \mathcal{N}_{x}$ such that $f_1 (R)\subseteq U_j$ and $f_2 (S)\subseteq V_j$. Take $R\cap S \in \mathcal{N}_{x}$ so that $f(R\cap S)=\{ f(z)\in X \times Y| z\in R\cap S\}$. Since $z\in R \cap S$, $f(z)=(f_1(z), f_2(z))\in f_1 (R)\times f_2 (S)\subseteq U_j \times V_j \subseteq \bigcup_{i\in I} (U_i \times V_i)=V$. Thus, $f(R\cap S)\subseteq V$. Hence $f$ is continuous. **Is this proof correct?**

---

**Summary:** There are two different approach to show $(\Rightarrow )$ and ($\Leftarrow$) implication.

**(1)** Munkres’ approach: Note $f_1 =\pi_1 \circ f$ and $f_2=\pi_2 \circ f$. Let $U\in \mathcal{T}_X$. Let $V\in \mathcal{T}_Y$. Clearly, $\pi_{1}^{-1}(U)= U\times Y \in \mathcal{T}_{X\times Y}$ and $\pi_{2}^{-1}(V)= X\times V \in \mathcal{T}_{X\times Y}$. Thus $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$ are continuous. By hypothesis of theorem $f$ is continuous. $f_1$ and $f_2$ are composite of continuous function, hence continuous.

**(2)** Sourav Ghosh: In my opinion, this is a clever approach. Rely on $f^{-1}(M\times N)=f_1^{-1}(M) \cap f_2^{-1}(N)$, where $M\subseteq X$ & $N\subseteq Y$, fact.

Conversely($\Leftarrow$),

**(1)** Munkres’ approach: suppose $f_1$ and $f_2$ are continuous. Let $U\times V\in \mathcal{B}$. Note $f^{-1}(U\times V)=f_1^{-1}(U) \cap f_2^{-1}(V)$. Since $f_1$ and $f_2$ are continuous, $U\in \mathcal{T}_X$ and $V\in \mathcal{T}_Y$, we have $f^{-1}(U\times V) \in \mathcal{T}_A$. Thus $f$ is continuous.

**(2)** Henno Brandsma: By theorem 15.2, $\pi_i^{-1}(U) \in S$, where $S=\{ \pi_1^{-1}(U)| U\in \mathcal{T}_X\} \cup \{ \pi_2^{-1}(V)|V\in \mathcal{T}_Y\}$ is subbasis for product topology on $X\times Y$(Proof: [Theorem 15.2 of Munkres Topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4342594/861687)) . To prove the continuity of $f$ it is suffice to show that inverse image of each subbasis element is open. $f^{-1}(\pi_i^{-1}(U)) = (\pi_i \circ f)^{-1}(U)= f_i^{-1}(U)\in \mathcal{T}_A$, since $f_i$ is continuous for $i=1,2$.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma It's a bit difficult to read your comment, but are you saying something to the effect of "Prove that this theorem is true but using the standard fact that this theorem is true"? Maybe that standard fact needs a proof before it is a fact?

Comment: @Arthur the standard factors in most textbooks. Just apply it.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Seems circular to me. Munkres is meant to be an _introduction_ to topology. "Standard facts" (at least within the field of topology) must therefore be proven before they can be used. This looks like the point in the book where this standard fact is proven. So using the standard fact is a no-go.

Comment: @Arthur this formulation is not in terms of projections. In the text (IIRC) this fact is mentioned and proved.

Comment: @user264745 he needs to apply the continuity of $f$ on these sets next perhaps?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma yeah I got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> (Maps into product) let $ f:A\to X×Y$ be given by equation
> $f(a)=(f_1(a),f_2(a))$  then $f$ is continuous if and only if the function
> $ f_1:A\to X $  and $ f_2:A\to Y$ are continuous

Proof : Given : $ f_1:A\to X $  and $ f_2:A\to Y$ are continuous.

To show : $f:A\to X×Y$ is continuous.

Choose an open set  $W\in \tau_{product}$.

Then $W=U×V $ where $U \in \tau_{X}$ and $V\in \tau_{X}$

Then, $f^{-1}(W) =f_1^{-1}(U) \cap f_2^{-1}(V)$

As $f_1^{-1}(U), f_2^{-1}(V)$ are open in $A$ as pre images of open sets under continuous maps.

Hence, $f^{-1}(W)$ is open in $A$.

Similarly if $f:A\to X×Y$ is continuous, then both $ f_1:A\to X $  and $ f_2:A\to Y$ are continuous.

Choose, $U\in\tau_{X}$.

\begin{align} f^{-1}(U×Y) &=f_1^{-1}(U) \cap f_2^{-1}(Y)\\& =f_1^{-1}(U)\cap A\\&=f_1^{-1}(U)\end{align}

As $U×Y\in \tau_{product}$ and $f:A\to X×Y$ is continuous $f^{-1}(U×Y)\subset A$ is open.

Hence, $f_1:A\to X$ is continuous.

Similarly , it can be easily shown that $f_2:A\to Y$ is also continuous.

Comment: You have made a mistake that everyone do, $W\in \mathcal{T}_p$ $\Rightarrow$ $W=U\times V$.

Comment: And how to show $f^{-1}(W) =f_1^{-1}(U) \cap f_2^{-1}(V)$ fact?

Comment: $a\in f^{-1}(W) \iff f(a) \in W=U×V \iff  f_1(a) \in U \text {and }f_2{(a)} \in V$

Answer (score 1):

Let $\pi_i^{-1}[U]$ be a subbasic open set, $i\in \{1,2\}$, $U$ open. Then $f^{-1}[\pi_i^{-1}[U]] = (\pi_i \circ f)^{-1}[U] = f_i^{-1}[U]$ is also open when both $f_i$ are. Hence $f$ is continuous (inverse images of subbasic sets are open). The other direction follows from the fact that compositions of continuous maps are continuous and $\pi_i \circ f = f_i$.

Comment: Woww.... Thank you so much for the answer.