# Theorem 19.6 of Munkres’ Topology

Tags: general-topology, continuity, proof-writing, solution-verification, alternative-proof

> Let $f:A\rightarrow \prod_{\alpha \in J} X_{\alpha}$ be given by $f(a)=(f_{\alpha}(a))_{\alpha \in J}.$ Where $f_{\alpha}:A\rightarrow X_{\alpha}$ for each $\alpha.$ Then $f$ is continuous iff $f_{\alpha}$  is continuous for each $\alpha$ provided the product space $\prod_{\alpha \in J} X_{\alpha}$ is  given product topology.

**My attempt:** ($\Rightarrow$)

**Approach(1):** let $x\in A$. Let $V_\alpha \in \mathcal{N}_{f_\alpha (x)}, \forall \alpha \in J$. Clearly $\prod_{\alpha} V_\alpha \in \mathcal{B}_p \subseteq \mathcal{T}_{p}$(product topology) and $f(x)= (f_{\alpha}(x)) \in \prod_{\alpha} V_\alpha$. So $\prod_{\alpha} V_\alpha \in \mathcal{N}_{f(x)}$. Since $f$ is continuous, $\exists Q\in \mathcal{N}_x$ such that $f(Q)\subseteq \prod_{\alpha} V_\alpha$. So $f(Q)=\{ f(z)\in \prod_{\alpha} X_\alpha |z\in Q\} \subseteq \prod_{\alpha} V_\alpha$. Thus $f(z)=(f_\alpha (z))\in \prod_{\alpha} V_\alpha, \forall z\in Q$. Which implies $f_\alpha (z)\in V_\alpha , \forall z\in Q$. Hence $f_\alpha (Q)\subseteq V_\alpha ,\forall \alpha \in J$. Thus $f_\alpha$ is continuous $\forall \alpha \in J$. **Is this proof correct?**

**Approach(2):** $\pi_{\beta}^{-1}(U_{\beta})= \prod_{\alpha} U_\alpha$, where $U_\alpha = X_\alpha ,\forall \alpha \in J\setminus \{ \beta \}$. $\pi_{\beta}^{-1}(U_{\beta})\in \mathcal{T}_p$, if $U_\beta \in \mathcal{T}_{X_\beta}$. Hence $\pi_{\beta}$ is continuous for all $\beta \in J$. Claim: $f_\beta =\pi_\beta \circ f$. Proof: $\pi_\beta \circ f (x)=\pi_{\beta}(f(x))=\pi_\beta ((f_\alpha (x))_{\alpha \in J})=f_\beta (x)$. $f_\alpha$ is composite of continuous maps, hence $f_\alpha$ is continuous forall $\alpha \in J$.

**Approach(3):** It is easy to check $f^{-1}(\prod V_{\alpha})=\bigcap_{\alpha \in J} f_{\alpha}^{-1}(V_{\alpha})$. Let $V_{\beta}\in \mathcal{T}_{X_\beta}$ and $\prod V_{\alpha} \in \mathcal{B}_p, V_\alpha =X_\alpha, \forall \alpha \in J\setminus \{ \beta \}$. So $f^{-1}(\prod V_{\alpha}) =f_{\beta}^{-1}(V_\beta)\cap A= f_{\beta}^{-1}(V_\beta)\in \mathcal{T}_{A}$. Hence $f_\beta $ is continuous for all $\beta \in J$. **Is this proof correct?**

---

($\Leftarrow $)
**Approach(1):** Similar proof [Theorem 18.4 of Munkres’ Topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4354297/861687) don’t work. Precisely, if $Q_\alpha \in \mathcal{N}_x ,\forall \alpha \in J$, then it is not necessary that $\bigcap_{\alpha \in J}Q_\alpha$ is open in $A$. Hence this approach **don’t work!**

**Approach(2):** $f^{-1}(\prod V_{\alpha})=\bigcap_{\alpha \in J} f_{\alpha}^{-1}(V_{\alpha})= A\bigcap (\bigcap_{\alpha \in F} f_{\alpha}^{-1}(V_{\alpha}))$, where $F$ is a finite subset of $J$. Since $f_\alpha$ is continuous, $\bigcap_{\alpha \in F} f_{\alpha}^{-1}(V_{\alpha})\in \mathcal{T}_A$. Thus $f^{-1}(\prod V_{\alpha}) \in \mathcal{T}_A$.

**Approach(3):** $f^{-1}(\pi_{\beta}^{-1}(U_\beta))=(\pi_\beta \circ f)^{-1}(U_\beta)=f_{\beta}^{-1}(U_\beta)\in \mathcal{T}_{A}$.

Comment: Approach (2) and (3) for $\Rightarrow$ seem fine (and are essentially the same argument). Perhaps I'm misunderstanding your notation, but it seems as if you're asserting an arbitrary product of open sets is open? This is not the case. Similarly, in the approaches for $\Leftarrow$, which you say don't work, you seem to miss that $V_{\alpha}=X_{\alpha}$ for all but finitely many $\alpha$, so the intersections you're looking at are effectively intersections of finitely many opens, hence open. As for the que, try writing down the complement.

Comment: @Thorgott Thanks for reviewing my attempt. Yeah you’re right, I messed up notation. I was implicitly assuming inverse of a basis element, but kept writing $\in \mathcal{T}_{...}$ which is technically wrong. My last que, I have tryed $\prod_{\alpha} (X_\alpha \setminus C_\alpha)=\prod X_\alpha \setminus \prod C_\alpha$? I known last claim is not true for $J=\{ 1,2 \}$

Comment: Note quite, you have to negate carefully. What does it meann for $(x_{\alpha})_{\alpha}\in\prod_{\alpha}X_{\alpha}$ to *not* be in $\prod_{\alpha}C_{\alpha}$? Does it mean that $x_{\alpha}\not\in C_{\alpha}$ *for all* $\alpha$ or that there *exists* an $\alpha$ such that $x_{\alpha}\not\in C_{\alpha}$?

Comment: @Thorgott second one

Comment: @Thorgott I have updated by approach 2 for $\Leftarrow$, thanks for pointing that out!